# Appium android buttons strange working

Tags: java, android, testing, appium

I have problem with testing my app which is intended for online shopping. I noticed that all buttons from application working but I have problem with system buttons(look at the picture). I’m using to recognize the button `UiAutomatorViewer`.

At the picture I’m trying add product to cart but when I’m click button “Dodaj”(means Add) the window closes but there are any actions in application,  the product should be added to cart. I tested this application manually and everything work correct.

I tried to operate the button in many ways but still nothing. Does anyone know how to solve it? It’s very important functions to testing for me.

[image]

```
public class Product extends MainPage {
private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

@FindBy(id = "com.mec.leroy:id/product_add_to_cart")
private WebElement addToCart;

@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@index='1']") //problem with button
private WebElement buttonAdd;

@FindBy(id = "com.mec.leroy:id/product_name")
private WebElement productName;

public Product(AndroidDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    this.driver = driver;
}


public Product addProduct() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"do koszyka\"));");
    addToCart.click();
    buttonAdd.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return new Product(driver);
}

public boolean productName() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    try {
        productName.getText();
        return true;
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Connector {
public AndroidDriver Settings() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    runAppium();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "33004db396a6c2d1"); // nazwa urządzenia
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
    capabilities.setCapability("noRest", "true");
    capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");

    // capabilities.setCapability("useKeystore", "true");
    //uruchomienie aplikacji z poziomu telefonu
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.mec.leroy");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.mec.leroy.main.activity.MainActivity");

    //inicjalizacja połączenia z Appium Server

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    return driver;

}
```

Comment: public AndroidDriver Settings() ??? This does even compile?

Comment: After you click “Dodaj” button, the dialog is getting closed?

Comment: Yes, everything compile, it's only part with settings. After click "Dodaj" button the dialog is closed, but doesn't add product to cart.

Comment: Can you try sending app to background for 0 secs after clicking 'Dodaj'?

Comment: Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: After clicking 'Dodaj' try: driver.runAppInBackground(0); Don't know if will work but give it a try

Comment: It didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using `UiAutomatorViewer` (that uses old **UiAutomator**), but in your tests you are providing **UiAutomator2**: important to know that these frameworks build snapshot xml in a different way, so your locator might be incorrect.

I suggest to try inspect and interact with your button using official [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases):

1. Install & launch it
2. Run the server via appium-desktop
3. Set exact the same capabilities you have in the code, create new session

Now you can inspect your elements and try to click your button from inspector.

Comment: I tried your soluton but it's the same problem. I used Appium Inspector and repeated process of adding product to cart and still nothing. The window is closed after click 'Dodaj' button, but no reaction from the application. https://streamable.com/6ejdz <- movie with the problem